# How Do I create an Xcode Source Editor Extension?

Tags: swift, xcode

I would like to create an Xcode Source Editor Extension. A tutorial from [this](https://nshipster.com/xcode-source-extensions/) website shows a template for this in the new project menu. However, as of Xcode 11.5, this is missing from the list of templates. Is there still a way to do this?

[image: Xcode Templates]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcodekit/creating_a_source_editor_extension),

> begin by creating a new macOS project in Xcode. Add a new Xcode Source Editor Extension target to your project

In other words, first create a new project. Then create a new target in said project. That target being an Xcode Source Editor Extension.

Comment: I feel so stupid; I already read that article, but somehow I missed that. Thanks.